# Vector Products (Torque)

Tags: vectors

[image: Question]

Question 6a)
$$
T= |\underline r \space\times \underline F|
$$
$$
OP =\underline r
$$
$$
x = |\underline r|\cos\theta
$$
$$
x = 0.8\cos40
$$
$$
x = 0.61\underline i
$$
$$
y = |\underline r|\sin\theta
$$
$$
y = 0.8\sin40
$$
$$
y = 0.51\underline j
$$
$$
\underline r = 0.61\underline i + 0.51\underline j
$$
$$
For\space \underline F
$$
$$
x = |\underline F|\cos\theta
$$
$$
x = 40\cos30
$$
$$
x = 20\sqrt{30}\underline i
$$
$$
y = |\underline F|\sin\theta
$$
$$
y = 40\sin30
$$
$$
y = 20\underline j
$$
$$
\underline F = 20\sqrt{30}\underline i + 20\underline j
$$
$$
T= |\underline r \space\times \underline F|
$$
$$
T= |(0.61\underline i + 0.51\underline j)\times (20\sqrt{30}\underline i + 20\underline j)|
$$
$$
T= |2.8\underline k|
$$
$$
T= 2.8\space Nm
$$

The answer is $37.6\space Nm\space $can someone please tell me how I have gone wrong or whether my whole method is wrong. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another (probably a simpler) approach. Remember that

$$
|{\bf A}\times {\bf B}| = |{\bf A}| |{\bf B}| \sin \theta_{AB}
$$

where $\theta_{AB}$ is the angle formed by ${\bf A}$ and ${\bf B}$. In your case

$$
|{\bf r}\times {\bf F}| = |{\bf r}| |{\bf F}| \sin \theta_{rF} = (0.8{\rm m})(50{\rm N})\sin(30^\circ+40^\circ) = 37.6~{\rm Nm}
$$

Comment: Yes much simpler! Thank you

Comment: Just what I was going to suggest.

Comment: @amd Thanks for catching that up